# how to test if a variable is pd.NaT?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, datetime, nan

I'm trying to test if one of my variables is pd.NaT. I know it is NaT, and still it won't pass the test. As an example, the following code prints nothing :

```
a=pd.NaT

if a == pd.NaT:
    print("a not NaT")
```

Does anyone have a clue ? Is there a way to effectively test if `a` is NaT?

Comment: `pd.isnull` also works for NaTs.

Comment: `pandas` and `numpy` follow the standard that `NaN` does not equate to itself. so even if you typed `a == a` you would get `False`

Comment: Voting to reopen because `pandas.NaT` isn't actually a NumPy `NaT`, and it behaves differently in equality and `numpy.isnat` checks.

Comment: @ALollz: NumPy doesn't actually do that yet; there's a `FutureWarning` saying they plan to, but for now, `numpy.datetime64('NaT') == numpy.datetime64('NaT')`.

Comment: *Related*: [Numpy: Checking if a value is NaT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509538/numpy-checking-if-a-value-is-nat)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the heads up! Good to know.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Pandas `NaT` behaves like a floating-point `NaN`, in that it's not equal to itself. Instead, you can use `pandas.isnull`:

```
In [21]: pandas.isnull(pandas.NaT)
Out[21]: True
```

This also returns `True` for None and NaN.

Technically, you could also check for Pandas `NaT` with `x != x`, following a common pattern used for floating-point NaN. However, this is likely to cause issues with NumPy NaTs, which look very similar and represent the same concept, but are actually a different type with different behavior:

```
In [29]: x = pandas.NaT

In [30]: y = numpy.datetime64('NaT')

In [31]: x != x
Out[31]: True

In [32]: y != y
/home/i850228/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/__main__.py:1: FutureWarning: In the future, NAT != NAT will be True rather than False.
  # encoding: utf-8
Out[32]: False
```

`numpy.isnat`, the function to check for NumPy `NaT`, also fails with a Pandas `NaT`:

```
In [33]: numpy.isnat(pandas.NaT)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-39a66bbf6513> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.isnat(pandas.NaT)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.
```

`pandas.isnull` works for both Pandas and NumPy NaTs, so it's probably the way to go:

```
In [34]: pandas.isnull(pandas.NaT)
Out[34]: True

In [35]: pandas.isnull(numpy.datetime64('NaT'))
Out[35]: True
```

Comment: Note that `pandas.isnull()` is an alias to `pandas.isna()`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov there must be something different.  I used this pattern: `df.apply(lambda x: ... if x.time.isna() else ..., axis=1)`.   In that case the following error is thrown: `AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isna'`.  But if I use `pd. isnull(x.time)`, it behaves as expected

Comment: @MikeB2019x you should be able to use `pd.isna(x.time)`

Answer (score 31):

```
pd.NaT is pd.NaT
```

True

this works for me.

Comment: good when you specifically want to check for NaT without including other null types

Answer (score 21):

You can also use pandas.isna() for pandas.NaT, numpy.nan or None:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = (pd.NaT, np.nan, None)
[pd.isna(i) for i in x]

Output:
[True, True, True]
```

Comment: isnull is an alias for isna. From pandas source code: "isnull = isna"

Answer (score 10):

If it's in a `Series` (e.g. `DataFrame` column) you can also use `.isna()`:

```
pd.Series(pd.NaT).isna()
# 0    True
# dtype: bool
```

Comment: Not sure this is true.  I had a df and was using "df.apply(lambda x: ... if x.time.isna() else ..., axis=1)".  In that case the following error was thrown: "AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isna'".

Comment: @MikeB2019x because `.isna()` is an attribute of the column (i.e. pd.Series), not of the element,.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me

```
>>> a = pandas.NaT
>>> type(a) == pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType
>>> True
```