# Unit testing python data types - test failed "Expected :NaT Actual:NaT"

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am introducing unit-testing my python data pipeline using `unittest` module.

Data class object example:

```py
class IsAvailable(Object)
    employee_id: int = Property()
    start_time: str = Property()
```

Unit test case:

```py
class TestIsAvailable(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.employee = pd.read_json('employee_leave.json', orient='records')
        self.isAvailable = IsAvailable()
        self.isAvailable.id = self.employee['start_time'][0]
```

```py
    def test_is_available_all_day_001(self):
        assert self.isAvailable.start_time == pd.NaT
```

test result:

```py
self = <tests.test_nodes.TestIsAvailable testMethod=test_is_available_all_day_001>

    def test_is_available_all_day_001(self):
        """test employee is available all day on specific day of the week"""
>       assert self.isAvailable.start_time == pd.NaT
E       AssertionError: assert NaT == NaT
E        +  where NaT = <IsAvailable id=1>.start_time
E        +    where <IsAvailable id=1> = <tests.test_nodes.TestIsAvailable testMethod=test_is_available_all_day_001>.isAvailable
E        +  and   NaT = pd.NaT
```

How do you test data types?

Comment: `pd.NaT` is not a dtype. Rather, it represents missing values for the datetime dtype. If you want to check for missing values in pandas dataframes, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435999/189418

Answer (score 0):

NaN and NaT explicitly do not equal themselves.

You can test this by running python in interactive mode and typing:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.NaT == pd.NaT
```

and similarly

```
pd.NaN == pd.NaN
```

You can explicitly test for NaN and NaT with

```
pd.isna(pd.NaT)
```