# Unable to get date column to read from xlsx file in pandas using read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, datetime

I have cells in Excel that are formatted as Date (see below):

[image: Format of cells in question is Date]

I couldn't get them to be read (they were NaN) and so I used a converter to attempt to convert them `to_datetime` when read from Pandas `read_excel` method:

```py
   cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(
                      i, 
                     ('sheet'+str(j)), 
                     headers = 1, skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, 
                     usecols = 'A:J', 
                     converters = {
                       'Expired': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce') , 
                   'Valid Until': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')})
```

And this resulted in all of them being loaded as `NaT`.

So, after consulting the documentation I tried it this way:

```py
    cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, parse_dates=True, skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J' )
```

Which resulted in `NaN` again.

And finally I tried it like this instead and also got `NaN` once more:

```py
    cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, parse_dates=True, date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'), skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J' )
```

The above did not work, because it tries to parse based on the index (see comment below).

```py
cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, parse_dates=['Expired', 'Valid Until'], skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J' )
```

```py
cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, parse_dates=['Expired', 'Valid Until'], skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J' )
```

```py
cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, parse_dates=['Expired', 'Valid Until'], dateparser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'), skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J' )
```

And both of these resulted in `NaT` (Not a Time?)

What else do I have to do to read a date?  I realize there is no time attached, but the way that [Excel stores dates and times](https://superuser.com/questions/736182/how-does-excel-handle-the-hmmss-format/736190#736190), it shouldn't matter as the time is stored as a decimal.

```
for i in glob.iglob(((str(xls_folder) + '\somesheets*.xlsx'))):
    cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J', converters = {'Expired': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce') , 'Valid Until': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')})

for w in cols_A8_J2007:
    print(cols_A8_J2007[w].dtypes)

Type                      object
Currency                  object
Initial Credit           float64
Credits                  float64
Debits                   float64
Balance                  float64
Reserved                   int64
Valid Until       datetime64[ns] <-  <- These I believe are what you are looking for..
Expired           datetime64[ns] <- These I believe are what you are looking for..
dtype: object
```

Also if this helps here are my versions:

```
pd.versions()
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.24.2
pytest: 4.5.0
pip: 19.1.1
setuptools: 41.0.1
Cython: 0.29.8
numpy: 1.16.4
scipy: 1.2.1
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 7.5.0
sphinx: 2.0.1
patsy: 0.5.1
dateutil: 2.8.0
pytz: 2019.1
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.5.1
numexpr: 2.6.9
feather: None
matplotlib: 3.0.3
openpyxl: 2.6.2
xlrd: 1.2.0
xlwt: 1.3.0
xlsxwriter: 1.1.8
lxml.etree: 4.3.3
bs4: 4.7.1
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.3.3
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.10.1
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
gcsfs: None
```

Comment: `parse_dates=True` parses the index. `parse_dates=['col1','col2']` parses the listed columns.

Comment: @QuangHoang That gave me `NaT` again and I tried it both with / without `date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')`.

Comment: You could always read them in as string and then convert to proper format but this may be unreasonable for you..

Comment: @leeand00 when you changed the format - did you re-save the excel file?

Comment: @JonClements yes; there are 7 of them.

Comment: @leeand00 okay... so what if we remove it to bare minimum of just `df = pd.read_excel('your work book.xlsx', nrows=2000)` and then check what `df.dtypes` has?

Comment: @JonClements I added the dtypes above but the table data is a bit lower down than like say a csv file would have, so that needs a bit of help there, that's why I was loading it like I was.

Comment: @JonClements I added the types I get again.  This time there are actual types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined the issue to be that I needed to check if the value was null using `pd.isnull`.  The file just had too many null values for me to be able to see them in the result set.  Found the answer here: [how to test if a variable is pd.NaT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435317/how-to-test-if-a-variable-is-pd-nat)

```
me_df = pd.read_excel(i, ('iCareAcctListing'+str(j)), headers = 1, skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J', converters = {'Expired': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce') , 'Valid Until': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')})

# Ran this and ended up with just the dates that were 
# filled in with actual values.
#
# There were so many nulls before and after that I couldn't see any of them in the dataset!
me_df[pd.isnull(me_df['Valid Until']) != True]
```