# How to properly declare 'NaT' in a python function to be applied on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to apply a function to a new `pandas` dataframe column.
The function should return something when pandas row is `NaT` and something else in all other cases.

The input is a `datetime64` class column.

Here's my attempt:

```
import numpy as np 

def some_fun(x):
    if np.isnat(x) == False:
        return 'something'
    else: 
        return 'something else'

df['new_col'] = np.vectorize(some_fun(df['date']))
```

Console Output:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

### data

```
    date
#0  NaT
#1  NaT
#2  NaT
#3  NaT
#4  2021-01-17
#5  NaT
#6  NaT
#7  NaT
#8  NaT
#9  NaT
```

Expected output:

```
    date         new_col
#0  NaT         something else
#1  NaT         something else
#2  NaT         something else
#3  NaT         something else
#4  2021-01-17  something
#5  NaT         something else
#6  NaT         something else
#7  NaT         something else
#8  NaT         something else
#9  NaT         something else
```

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: In your code, think of x as a Series  - so the conditional only makes sense is you also specify if you want to look for any or all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code does what you want. also, I made some changes to your code.

```
def some_fun(x):
  
  if pd.isnull(x):
    return 'something else'
  else: 
    return 'something'

df['new_col'] = [some_fun(x) for x in df['date']]
```

unfortunately, `np.isnat()` failed in my code. so I used `pd.isnull()` instead according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435999/11988587). if you think that'll work for you, use `np.isnat()`.

### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I think  `pd.notnull()` would suit better  for `some_fun(x)`  as the first `if` statement equals `False`; however this partially solves the issue, so I am accepting it.

Comment: I changed the order of if statement. but you are right. if you want to keep the original order `pd.notnull()` would be the right choice.