# NumPy - Testing equality including np.nan, np.nat, np.NZERO and np.PZERO in a vectorized way

Tags: python, numpy, equality

I basically want to write a vectorized function in Numpy that will element-wise compare the *binary representations* and the *data types* of involved arrays.

For example,

- `f(np.nan, np.nan)` should be `True`.
- `f(np.datetime64('NaT'), np.nan)` should be `False`.
- `f(np.datetime64('NaT'), np.datetime64('NaT'))` should be `True`.
- `f(np.NZERO, np.PZERO)` should be `True` on platforms that have an identical binary representation for both but `False` otherwise.
- Any other weird exceptions (?)

Also, the function should be vectorized, fast (C speed) and at least "look like" a `ufunc` in the sense that it should support broadcasting and stringing over arrays.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work for `NaT`, etc: [Comparing NumPy arrays so that NaNs compare equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819715/comparing-numpy-arrays-so-that-nans-compare-equal)

The following require Pandas, which I don't want to do, and they'll make `NaN == NaT`. [Numpy: Checking if a value is NaT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509538/numpy-checking-if-a-value-is-nat)

I could add `np.isnat` to problem 1, but that wouldn't compare the precision of the object.

And none of these can do the `NZERO`/`PZERO` thing.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show us what you've tried and ask *specific* questions about single problems that you're having.

Comment: @PaulH I edited to show what problems I've had with existing solutions.

Comment: Are you aware that there's more than one NaN representation? There are like 9 million billion of them. What should happen if you're comparing two different NaNs?

Comment: @user2357112 I wasn't aware, but thanks for alerting me to it. In any case, like I said, I only want the _binary representation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems comparing the underlying `view` does exactly what I want:

```
def compare(x, y):
    x, y = np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)
    dtx = x.dtype
    dty = y.dtype
    if dtx != dty:
        return np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
    xv = x.view((np.uint8, x.itemsize))
    yv = y.view((np.uint8, y.itemsize))
    return np.all(xv == yv, axis=-1)
```

Comment: `'uint8'` is better spelt `np.uint8`

Comment: @Eric Good catch! Unfortunately, I noticed this doesn't work with scalars and 0-d arrays. If you have a better answer, feel free to post and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've modified it to support scalars and implemented your suggestion, @Eric.

Comment: You could also use `xv = x.view((np.uint8, x.itemsize))`, which works on 0d arrays